# PHP preg_match help please. Pretty simple

Tags: php, security, preg-match

How do I add into the list of items allowed `(gif$|jpg$|png$|jpeg$)`

into the following code

```
$regexp = "/[0-9a-zA-z\.]/";
if (preg_match($regexp, $imageInput))
```

also how do I add in an exclude list e.g so stop people unploading .exe files etc.

Thanks

**EDIT**

I fixed it with the following code

any advice on how to make it better ?

```
$regexp = "/^[a-zA-z0-9._-]+(gif|jpg|png|jpeg)/";
```

Comment: I hope you’re aware of that `[0-9a-zA-z\.]` describes just *one* character.

Comment: Hope do you mean ? Could you explain a little. Im not to regex

Comment: to match multiple characters use `[0-9a-zA-Z\.]+` (one or more) or `[0-9a-zA-Z\.]*` (zero or more)

Comment: you need a $ at the end to prevent foo.jpeg.exe.

Answer (score 4):

Use a positive list:

```
/^[0-9a-zA-z\.]+\.(gif|jpg|png|jpeg)$/
```

Or a negative lookahead:

```
/^[0-9a-zA-z\.]+\.(?!exe$)[a-z]+$/
```

A positive list is the safer, but more restrictive option.

Comment: That wouldn’t allow `foo.execute` neither.

Comment: @Gumbo: Thanks, that can be fixed by using (?!exe$).

Answer (score 1):

change your regex to `/([0-9a-zA-z\.])(gif|jpg|png|jpeg)$/` this will only allow for the extensions you have specified.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$regexp = "/^[0-9a-zA-z\.]+\.(jpg|gif|png)$/";
```

for a stopping-pattern use `'/.(exe|cmd|bat|sh)$/'` and then `if(!preg_match($pattern, $text))`

Comment: Thanks for the help i actually fixed it by myself after a few minutes apart from it thanks :)